# Solution to gravitational two-body problem in case of hyperbolic orbits

Tags: newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

Given two bodies and their positions and velocities at a given time $t_0$, as well as their masses, and the knowledge that their relative velocity is high enough that they will not be gravitationally bound to each other as they pass by (so, hyperbolic orbits), I am trying to figure out a way to calculate their positions and velocities as a function of time.

The masses are such that we can't make the Keplerian approximation that one mass is much greater than the other.  I know, though, that the gravitational two-body problem can be reduced to an equivalent one-body Keplerian-like problem.

Once the semimajor axis of the orbit is calculated ($a= -G(m_1 + m_2)/(2E)$, where $E$ is the total specific energy) then the magnitude of the relative velocity $v$ can be calculated as a function of the magnitude of the separation $r$ using the [vis viva equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vis-viva_equation):

$$v^2 = G(m_1+m_2)\left(\frac{2}{r} - \frac{1}{a}\right).$$

This, however, only gives the magnitude of the relative velocity as a function of separation between the two objects.  I am hoping to find the full position and velocity vectors of the objects as a function of time.

This is solved in many books and on many websites for the bound case, where the orbits are elliptical.  I have not yet found anywhere that does it for the hyperbolic case though.

Comment: Is it given that the bodies are in a mutual hyperbolic orbit? In a hyperbolic orbit, the two bodies wouldn't collide. You'd need an elliptical orbit (technically a circular orbit) for the two masses to collide.

Comment: @barrycarter, I disagree.  An orbit of any shape that has a periapse that puts the two objects closer together than the sum of their radii will collide.

Comment: Just to confirm, "unbound gravitationally" means they are affected only by each others' gravity? Or that their gravitational attraction towards each other is effectively zero? This may just be a simple conservation-of-momentum problem?

Comment: @barrycarter, affected only by each others' gravity.

Comment: Quoting https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall (which also has the equations the OP needs) "The motion of two objects moving radially towards each other with no angular momentum can be considered a special case of an **elliptical** orbit" (emphasis added). However, the OP changed the question so it no longer involves collisions.

Comment: @barrycarter The objects are not moving radially towards each other.  They have angular momentum.

Comment: If they have angular momentum and are point masses, they will enter into an orbit and not collide. OP, suggest you post this on space.stackexchange.com or something if you'd like.

Comment: @barrycarter, they are not point masses.  I never said they were.

Comment: OK, you say in the post "This is solved in many books and on many websites for the bound case, where the orbits are elliptical". All of the solutions I've seen assume point masses.

Comment: @barrycarter, until collision, the dynamics of point particles and non-deformable extended bodies with spherically symmetric mass distributions are identical.